# Creating pandas DataFrame without inferring dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a dataframe from a (large) list of lists (inner lists are rows). `pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=my_columns)` generally does the job but I would like to customize the dtypes of the resulting dataframe. Some of the columns can be stored at lower precision (np.float32), others are integers that actually represent timestamps (in numpy representation, e.g. `my_ts = np.datetime64(my_int, 'ns')`). Unfortunately, the DataFrame constructor only allows to specify a single dtype. Is there another way to achieve what I want?

I could, of course, cast the data as follows:

```
df['some_col'] = df['some_col'].astype(desired_type)
```

but that involves a lot of copying and my dataset is quite large.

When we construct the DataFrame pandas copies data from the python list on top of whatever algorithm it uses to infer the types (the only safe way to infer the types is to scan the entire dataset). If only we could hint the dtypes to it we could save on both copying and dtype inference.